# Certain characters are not rendered

Tags: fonts, gnome

There are certain characters that are not being rendered on any application on GNOME (3.22.2). I believe this is because there is no fallback font.

[image: Screenshot showing unrendered characters]

I checked the Fonts tab in Tweak, and the interface font is "Canterell Regular". There is no option there for choosing a fallback font.

What do I need to do to fix this so that these characters are readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no fallback font, then make sure to **install** a fallback font. For Korean, you could try (in no particular order):

- fonts-nanum
- fonts-noto (Google Noto, same as Adobe Source Han Sans)
- fonts-unfonts-core fonts-unfonts-extra (Un fonts)
- Windows "Malgun Gothic" (copy malgun*.ttf from C:\Windows\Fonts to ~/.local/share/fonts)

Pango-based programs will choose a matching fallback font automatically.

Comment: This question is specific to GNOME. How do I install a fallback font on GNOME?

Comment: Font installation is in no way whatsoever specific to GNOME. GNOME does not have its own font library nor its own fallback font configuration. The fonts are installed through your distribution's packages, the font library is managed by Fontconfig and the font fallback is implemented via Pango.

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't fully understand the answer until your comment. But now I understand and have installed a fallback font.